# Running Geonode solr application

Tags: django, geonode, solr

I am trying to follow these steps http://www.paolocorti.net/foss4g_2017_geonode_solr/10_customization.html but I installed geonode using the quick start tutorial http://geonode.org/#install. I am not able to run the solr app. I think the paths and configuration should be different and I tried changes like changing

- `mkdir geonode/solr` to `mkdir solr`
- `python manage.py startapp solr geonode/solr` to `geonode startapp solr solr`
- `# solr application urls
  urlpatterns += patterns('',
  url(r'^solr/', include('geonode.solr.urls')),
  )` 
  to
  `# solr application urls
  urlpatterns += patterns('',
  url(r'^solr/', include('solr.urls')),
  )`

But I cannot get it to work

---

- Figured out path. change `cd /workshop/geonode` to `cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Now I get `Error occurred while trying to load geonode.urls: name 'patterns' is not defined`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`patterns` must be defined in geonode/urls.py.
Edit geonode/urls.py and add:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally working:

`'patterns'` is not defined in `geonode/urls.py`. Edit geonode/urls.py and add the following in the imports:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
```